# Is there a way to upload multiple configurations at once to a test case in alm using vba/macro?

Tags: vba, excel, alm

I have situation where-in I need to add multiple configurations to test cases in HP-ALM(Application Lifecycle Management).

Adding 100s of configurations manually is mundane task.

Is there a way to upload multiple configurations at once using macro/vba for a test case in ALM?

For instance: I have a test step as below where a parameter 'field' is added and I want to execute this test case with different field values in separate test cases. If there are 100 fields in a table to be verified I would have to manually add 100 configs for a single test case in alm. Wondering if there is any vba script which can export configs placed in an excel column and map it to a specified test id.

In this instance I have to add configs to my test case for all fields(EmpID, EmpName, EmpDesignation etc.) in a table to be verified:

config1: Verify_EmpID_in_Table-XYZ
config2: Verify_EmpName_in_Table-XYZ
config3: Verify_EmpDesignation_in_Table-XYZ

Comment: Yes, it is possible using OTA. Can you add a sample config in your question?

Comment: I have added a sample config for a sample test case. Let me know if more info to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to upload bulk configurations using TestId

```
Sub Add_Configurations()

Dim qcURL As String
Dim qcID As String
Dim qcPWD As String
Dim qcDomain As String
Dim qcProject As String
Dim tdConnection As Object

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:


   Set cnf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("config")

   qcURL = cnf.Cells(1, 2)
   qcID = cnf.Cells(2, 2)
   qcPWD = cnf.Cells(3, 2)
   qcDomain = cnf.Cells(4, 2)
   qcProject = cnf.Cells(5, 2)


    Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
    tdConnection.InitConnectionEx qcURL
    tdConnection.Login qcID, qcPWD
    tdConnection.Connect qcDomain, qcProject


   lastrow = cnf.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 2 To lastrow
      Test_Id = cnf.Cells(i, 5)
      Set myTest = tdConnection.TestFactory.Item(Test_Id)
      Set aNewConfig = myTest.TestConfigFactory.AddItem(Null)
      aNewConfig.Name = cnf.Cells(i, 6)
      aNewConfig.Post
      Set aNewConfig = Nothing
   Next

MsgBox "Configurations successfully exported to ALM" & Chr(10) & "Please refresh to view the configurations"
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox "!!!!! Error in exporting configurations !!!!!" & Chr(10) & "possible error causes: " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "1. Duplicate configuration name" & Chr(10) & "2. Configuration name is blank for a test id"
Exit Sub

End Sub
```